# Filte routes after login with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have devise configured in a rails apps. If my users login and come back later to the login page i want the sessiones to be invalid.

How can i achieve this?

```
GET /users/sign_in(.:format)    devise/sessions#new
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a (simple) way to close a session via Devise without some trickery or manual action (rake db:session:clear) ... but, you can set a [session timeout via Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically).

I believe an appropriately timed time out should accomplish what you are looking for.